# Where is my App Package Deployment in Group Policy Editor

Tags: group-policy, sideloading

I've installed visual studio to code and develop a windows store app using HTML5. but It seemed that I didn't have any developer license so I searched on net and found out that I can change the whole policy in this way:
1.Open the Group Policy Editor by typing ‘gpedit.msc’ and running it
2.Change the following settings:
   *Computer configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\App Package Deployment\Allow all trusted apps to install – ENABLED
   *Computer configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\App Package Deployment\Allow development of Windows Store apps without installing a developer license – ENABLED

but there is no "App Package Deployment" in this address
 [This is what I see in the group policy editor (Screen Shot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSmC4.jpg)

What should I do now?? how can I access to the folder App Package Deployment???

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the 2012R2 Group Policy Templates

Download Windows8.1-Server2012R2ADMX-RTM.msi

This will allow you to edit local group policy on your local machine with required settings present.